# Google Cloud Platform failure to complete job - permissions error?

Tags: tensorflow, image-processing, google-cloud-platform, google-compute-engine, tensorflow2.0

I am trying to use the GCP to train a computer vision project.
I am using the AI platform.

When I submit my job, it fails with the following error:

message: ....does not have storage.objects.list access to NAME OF BUCKET REMOVED FOR SECURITY
 "domain": "global",
        "reason": "forbidden"

Any suggestions of where to start to fix this?
Does it matter that my project location and bucket location are different?

Thanks!

Comment: **1**. Have a look at the documentation  [Cloud IAM roles for Cloud Storage](https://cloud.google.com/storage/docs/access-control/iam-roles) section [Predefined roles](https://cloud.google.com/storage/docs/access-control/iam-roles#standard-roles) and grant to your service account role Storage Admin (`roles/storage.admin`) and try again. **2**. Have you already created a bucket before running this job? **3**. Which roles/permissions does your service account have?

Comment: thanks @SerhiiRohoza - I will look into these suggestions. I created this bucket for this job, had no issues copying files to it, etc.

Comment: Please let me know when you check permissions. If you still have an issue, please provide more details like in which way you grant permissions to your job.

Comment: I added service-ZZZZ@cloud-tpu.iam.gserviceaccount.com  (with ZZZZ replaced by my key) to the bucket permissions as the "Environment and Storage Object Administrator" role and the job has not failed yet -- but looking at the TensorBoard, it is not making any progress.

Comment: Job completed! Thank you!

Comment: Thank you for confirmation! Please mark my answer as accepted if my suggestions were helpful for you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**This problem caused by insufficient IAM permissions**. More information you can find in the documentation like  [Cloud IAM roles for Cloud Storage](https://cloud.google.com/storage/docs/access-control/iam-roles) section [Predefined roles](https://cloud.google.com/storage/docs/access-control/iam-roles#standard-roles).

**To solve this issue** you should grant to your service account [Storage Admin](https://cloud.google.com/storage/docs/access-control/iam-roles#standard-roles) role (`roles/storage.admin`) or you can use other IAM roles to grant permissions `storage.objects.*` (in some cases permissions `storage.buckets.*` could be required) like [Environment and Storage Object Administrator](https://cloud.google.com/iam/docs/understanding-roles#cloud-composer-roles) role (`roles/composer.environmentAndStorageObjectAdmin`) you've mentioned above.